# adjust posts size into columns wordpress

Tags: css

in this link:
https://teesvg.com/downloads/husband-and-wife-svg-png/

if you go down until More from this Category, you will find 4 posts in two columns. I want that they show up in 4 columns and smaller like this picture[image]

Comment: Check with your theme's support team.

Comment: What CSS styles have you tried thus far?